# How to find windows certificate which is autoenrolled by CA server after domain joining

Tags: windows, certificate, embedded-linux, wifi

I have setup 802.1x PEAP-EAP-TLS  wired authentication on windows NPS radius Server . So, to connect windows client machine with peap-eap-tls method  ,first  i need to joined windows machine with domain server and after that i have to connect machine with 802.1x Ethernet port and it will connect with 802.1x network successfully. So , i have doubts regarding certificates below :

1) How to find out certificates which are autoenrolled by CA Server after joining the domain ? because as i know , to connect with peap-eap-tls the client machine requires client certificate , root certificate ,identity , private key .

2)Is there any method to export the window certificate with private key which is non-exportable ?

3)it good if anyone knows how to manually create certificates for peap-eap-tls method ?

4) Is it possible to connect linux client machine with peap-eap-tls method ? if yes/No then how / why  ?

Answer (score 0):

PEAP-EAP-TLS encrypts the EAP-TLS certificate transfer with a PEAP Tunnel. So you will need an identity, user identity password and a root certificate, client certificate and a private key. The relevant root certificate can be exported from the CA. This can be done via `https://<your domain name>/certsrv` service of your authentication server and by logging in with your identity and password.

In order to get the client certificate, you might have to generate a private key locally, use that to generate a client certificate request, log-in to certsrv with your user name and password, select "Request a certificate" -> "advanced certificate request", copy paste the full content of the certificate request you created and press "Submit". You can create the private key and the certificate requests using OpenSSL by entering the following commands.

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:1024 -nodes -keyout <enter a name for your private key here>.pem -out <enter a name for your certificate request here>.pem
```

For example,

```
sudo openssl req -new -newkey rsa:1024 -nodes -keyout privkey.pem -out certreq.pem
```

There is no proper method to export Windows certificates with private keys which is non-exportable. There are tools like Mimikatz that could be useful though.